# Dynamically creating a list of css values in SCSS based on array

Tags: css, sass

I'd like to do is create a list of margin css classes based on am array of numbers.

e.g. i'd like my css to look like this.

> .ml-5 { margin-left: 5px; }
>
> .ml-10 { margin-left: 10px; }
>
> .ml-15 { margin-left: 15px; }

I want to do something like the following in my SCSS file to generate these for a set list of numbers

```
$list: 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30;

@each $n in $list {
    .ml-$n: margin-left:$n;
}
```

Anyone know if this can be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were pretty close actually. You can use this syntax to generate the desired classes:

```
$list: 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30;

@each $n in $list {
    .ml-#{$n} { margin-left:$n; }
}
```

the `#{$n}` is called [interpolation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_) and is required to make your variables accessible in the way needed here.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you for your answer - just what I need!

Comment: You are very welcome. Thanks for your reply. Have a good time!

Answer (score 3):

Try this one for better result

```
$spaceamounts: (5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 75, 100); // Adjust this to include the pixel amounts you need.
$sides: (top, bottom, left, right); // Leave this variable alone

@each $space in $spaceamounts {
  @each $side in $sides {
    .m#{str-slice($side, 0, 1)}-#{$space} {
      margin-#{$side}: #{$space}px !important;
    }
  }
}
```

Results

```
.mt-5 {
  margin-top: 5px !important;
}

.mb-5 {
  margin-bottom: 5px !important;
}

.ml-5 {
   margin-left: 5px !important;
}

.mr-5 {
  margin-right: 5px !important;
}
...
...
```

Comment: That's great, thank you so much for your answer, unfortunately you were slightly slower than Nico, otherwise I would have give you the answer.